# Create a new row based on other column values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe as below:

```
c1      c2
111     null    
null    222
333     444
null    null
```

I need to have a final dataframe with an additional column like below

```
c1      c2      new_col
111     null    111
null    222     222
333     444     333
333     444     444
null    null    null
```

If both cols are having values, then I need to create a new row with values from both cols1 and col2.
This is my code below as of now.

```
df = df.withColumn('new_col', when(col('c1').isNull(), col('c2')) \
        .otherwise(when(col('c2').isNull(), col('c1')).otherwise(col(c2'))))
```

Im stuck to create a new row if both columns c1 and c2 are having vaules, to create a new row.
Can anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2):

New row can be created with `unionAll`. On Scala, can be translated to Python easily:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", coalesce($"c1", $"c2"))
  .unionAll(
    df.where($"c1".isNotNull && $"c2".isNotNull)
      .withColumn("new_col", $"c2")
  )
```

Result:

```
+----+----+-------+
|c1  |c2  |new_col|
+----+----+-------+
|111 |null|111    |
|null|222 |222    |
|333 |444 |333    |
|null|null|null   |
|333 |444 |444    |
+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: final_df = df.withColumn("new_col", F.coalesce("c1", "c2")).unionAll(
    df.filter( (df["c1"].isNotNull()) & (df["c2"].isNotNull()) ).withColumn("new_col", df["c2"])
  )

final_df.show()

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(111, None), (None, 222), (333, 444), (None, None)]
columns = ["c1", "c2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df = df.withColumn("c1", F.col("c1").cast('int'))
df = df.withColumn("c2", F.col("c2").cast('int'))

df1 = df.filter((F.col("c1").isNotNull()) & (F.col("c2").isNotNull()))
df2 = df.filter(~((F.col("c1").isNotNull()) & (F.col("c2").isNotNull())))


df1 = (df1.withColumn("new_col", F.array(df["c1"], df["c2"]))
       .withColumn("new_col", F.explode("new_col"))
       .withColumn("new_col", F.col("new_col").cast("int")))

df2 = df2.withColumn("new_col", F.when(df2["c1"].isNull(), df2["c2"])
                     .when(df2["c2"].isNull(), df2["c1"])
                     .when((df2["c2"].isNull() & df2["c1"].isNull()), F.lit(None).cast('int'))
                     .otherwise(F.lit(None).cast('int')))

df1.show()
df2.show()


final_df = df2.unionByName(df1)
final_df.show()
```

here is the result , should be you desired output

```
+----+----+-------+
|  c1|  c2|new_col|
+----+----+-------+
| 111|NULL|    111|
|NULL| 222|    222|
|NULL|NULL|   NULL|
| 333| 444|    333|
| 333| 444|    444|
+----+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `coalesce` to create an array and then use `explode` to create rows out of it:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, explode, coalesce

df \
.withColumn(
    "array_col",
    expr(
        "CASE WHEN c1 IS NOT NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL THEN array(c1, c2)" +
        "ELSE array(coalesce(c1, c2))" +
        "END"
    )
) \
.withColumn("new_col", explode("array_col")) \
.drop("array_col") \
.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+-------+
|  c1|  c2|new_col|
+----+----+-------+
| 111|NULL|    111|
|NULL| 222|    222|
| 333| 444|    333|
| 333| 444|    444|
|NULL|NULL|   NULL|
+----+----+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired result, you can use the `union` operation to combine the DataFrame with a modified version of itself where the new column (`new_col`) is populated based on the conditions you mentioned. Here's how you can do it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Sample DataFrame
data = [(111, None), (None, 222), (333, 444), (None, None)]
columns = ["c1", "c2"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Create a new DataFrame with a modified new_col
new_df = df.withColumn("new_col", F.when(df["c1"].isNull(), df["c2"])
                                 .when(df["c2"].isNull(), df["c1"])
                                 .otherwise(F.array(df["c1"], df["c2"])))

# Explode the array in new_col to create separate rows
result_df = new_df.select("c1", "c2", F.explode("new_col").alias("new_col"))

# Show the result
result_df.show()
```

This will give you the following DataFrame:

```
+----+----+-------+
|  c1|  c2|new_col|
+----+----+-------+
| 111|null|    111|
|null| 222|    222|
| 333| 444|    333|
| 333| 444|    444|
|null|null|   null|
+----+----+-------+
```

Here, `F.array(df["c1"], df["c2"])` is used to create an array column `new_col` that contains both `c1` and `c2` values. The `F.explode` function is then used to explode this array into separate rows. This way, you get a new row for each value in the array.

Comment: I used the code below, but Im getting invalid syntax:
```
new_df = df.withColumn("new_col", F.when(df["c1"].isNull(), df["c2"]) \
                                 F.when(df["c2"].isNull(), df["c1"]) \
                                 F.otherwise(F.array(df["c1"], df["c2"])))
```

Comment: This answer is false , when : # Create a new DataFrame with a modified new_col , he is literally trying to create the same column "new_col" with ARRAY type and INT  type , wich is not possible

Comment: I'm getting datatype mismatch error.

Comment: is it possible to put empty string ('') instead of null in same column?